# "Unavailable website", because the cache emptied when offline?

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, offline, offline-mode

I must have missed something obvious.
I make a pwa for the offline mode.
I cache files with a Service Worker.
I see them in Cache storage.

But when i go offline, and hit F5, the website appears unavailable.
And i see the Cache storage is empty.
And when i get online again, the storage is here.

What is going on dear dev ?

[cache emptied when offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GL68.png)

Answer (score 1):

DevTools will only let you inspect the cache associated with the current origin for the web page that's open.

If you're offline and don't show a fallback page via your service worker, then you'll see the standard "No Internet" page—on Chrome, this is the "offline dino" game.

The URL for this page is set to `chrome-error://chromewebdata/` and the origin is set to `null`:

[image: offline dino and devtools]

Because the origin doesn't match the origin of your actual web application, there's nothing shown in the Cache viewer in DevTools.

Comment: Thank you to answer me. When i add a fallback page, it get stuck on it. When i try to reach my second page, it goes back to the first one systematically. But you're right, when i add this fallback to index.php, i still see the Cache storage. So why i can't reach another page since i see all the files in the Cache storage ?. I only want the pages to be accessible offline from the cache. Maybe my MVC/php architecture doesn't fit the PWA system ?